# Any idea why this formula would through an error on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

[image]=SUMIFS('Test 2021'!M3:M200,'Test 2021'!H3:H200,"Cualitativo",'Test 2021'!K3:K200,"Gestores")

Comment: looks good. share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Updated with a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your locale may require the use of semi-colons instead of comma's. So see if this works:

```
=SUMIFS('Test 2021'!M3:M200;'Test 2021'!H3:H200;"Cualitativo";'Test 2021'!K3:K200,"Gestores")
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Test 2021'!H3:H200="Cualitativo";'Test 2021'!K3:K200="Gestores"; 'Test 2021'!M3:M200)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUMIFS('Test 2021'!M3:M200*1; 'Test 2021'!H3:H200, "Cualitativo"; 
                                     'Test 2021'!K3:K200; "Gestores")
```

Comment: It didn't work either, it looks like it doesn't like the second 'Test 2021'!H3:H200,

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?